# PHPUnit - Test class not found

Tags: php, phpunit

When I am trying to test a class, it can't find the class to be tested.

Under the following line you see the test:

```
    <?php

class FacebookRestTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testFacebookFirstTest()
    {
        $pageid = 634336563297055;
        $since = 1438387200;
        $until = 1443052800;

        $facebook = new FacebookRest(new DataReader(new Report($pageid, $since, $until)));
        $page = $facebook->getPage();
        $this->assertTrue(!empty($page));
    }
}
```

But when I run the test in the terminal, it throws an error that it can't find the FacebookRest class.

Here is the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'FacebookRest' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/faceboo1/tests/FacebookRestTest.php on line 11
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Test filename is: FacebookRestTest and the class to be tested is FacebookRest.

Comment: try making the file name and class name exactly the same

Comment: What you mean? Making the FacebookRestTest class into FacebookRest?

Comment: Where is `FacebookRest` located? What is it's namespace? Add to top of test file `use Namespace\To\FacebookRest;`

Comment: Wont work? Because then it tries to run $facebook->getPage() on the test?

Comment: Rene: I got this filestucture: classes/FacebookRest.php and my test is in tests/FacebookRestTest.php

Comment: Do you have namespace for it? Are you using composer?

Comment: Im using composer yes, but namespace no?

Comment: can you share your composer.json here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included your class.

Add on top of your `FacebookRestTest` file:

```
include_once __DIR__.'/../classes/FacebookRest.php';
```

Comment: Get this Warning: include_once(../classes/FacebookRest.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/faceboo1/tests/FacebookRestTest.php on line 2

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../classes/FacebookRest.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.34/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/faceboo1/tests/FacebookRestTest.php on line 2
PHPUnit 4.8.9 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


Fatal error: Class 'FacebookRest' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/faceboo1/tests/FacebookRestTest.php on line 12

Comment: Edited my answer. Try again.

Comment: Still error: Warning: include_once(/../classes/FacebookRest.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/faceboo1/tests/FacebookRestTest.php on line 2

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/../classes/FacebookRest.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.34/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/faceboo1/tests/FacebookRestTest.php on line 2
PHPUnit 4.8.9 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


Fatal error: Class 'FacebookRest' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/faceboo1/tests/FacebookRestTest.php on line 12

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Edited it again.

Comment: You could also replace `dirname(__FILE__)` with `__DIR__` for prettification.

Comment: Sure. Thanks @jeromegamez. Edited my answer.